# ORA-01084: invalid argument in OCI call

Tags: xml, vb.net, oracle, stored-procedures, clob

I'm getting "ORA-01084: invalid argument in OCI call" error when I'm passing string.empty or "" to input parameter of below stored procedure through my vb.net code.

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE  SP_NAME
    (
      in_xml IN CLOB,
    )
    IS
    BEGIN
SELECT  xml.ID,
        xml.Name
        FROM XMLTABLE
        ('root/child' passing XMLTYPE(in_xml)
            columns
        ID NUMBER PATH 'ID',
        Name VARCHAR2(50)PATH 'Name') xml

    EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
        WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20999, 'SP_NAME'||SQLCODE||'-'||SQLERRM) ;
    END SP_NAME;
```

Below is the code used to call SP.

```
    Public Class DAL
    Private _db As Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database
    Dim param(0) As Object
    param(0) = String.Empty
    _db.ExecuteNonQuery(SP_NAME, param)
    End Class
```

PS. I've a specific scenario where I need to pass empty string to stored procedure.

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting us to say. You have eviscerated the procedure so we can't give you any advice on how to fix the code. If you want help you need to provide us with something to go on.

Comment: I've updated the procedure if it helps. I extract in_xml in select statement and perform update to some other table. I've one more flag parameter stating if in_xml has xml data. If its false I don't perform xml extract. But the issue is I'm not able to pass String.Empty or "" to IN parameter(in_xml) It throws "ORA-01084: invalid argument in OCI call"